# Why Docker container is running but localhost shows only "it works"?

Tags: docker, localhost

I used Docker version 19.03.13 and run Docker in Windows 10.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Run command line as below (this is from the [Docker 101](https://www.docker.com/101-tutorial))

`docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`

2. Confirm the container is running by execute the command line as below

`docker ps`  and `docker info`

3. open localhost in web browser
4. The localhost shows the "it works!" page only, nothing related to the docker/getting-started page.

Not sure why the container is running, but localhost is not connect to it and only showing the "it works" page?

Here's the "it works" page
[image]

Comment: What's the specific problem you're encountering?  Can you provide the application source code or sequence of commands that demonstrates it?  (As plain text directly in the question, please; do not post screen shots of terminal windows.)

Comment: What is the "It works" page from? Maybe something else is bound on port 80?

Comment: When I search Google, it makes me think that's a page maybe from Apache? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it+works%22+page Do you have an Apache server bound on port 80?

Comment: I am only running one container though. I added the localhost "it works" page back in the post.

Comment: Thanks but I don't recall I run the Apache server on localhost.

Comment: If you stop the container, do you still see this page?

Answer (score 0):

i would clear your temporary internet files and cookies, and to go further, stop the container, and use the `fuser` command. An example is shown below,

`fuser -v -n tcp 80`
`-v` is for verbose mode, and `-n` is used to select the corresponding name
space.

If an application is using port 80, then you can stop this program, or change the port you would like to use for your container.